# sql stored procedure - i would like to change it to a job but it has parameters

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a VERY long running, heavy stored procedure, so I would like to change it over to a job that runs every night and updates a table so the user can run it quickly during the day.  My problem is that it takes parameters IN THE LEFT JOIN, so I don't see how I could do it.  I tried to remove the parameters from the joins and just take all the records, but first problem with that is that these left joins are joins to table valued functions with group by clauses (so it's tons of records now) and also when I did it, it crashed my whole server.  I will post part of my stored proc to give you an idea of what i'm doing for now.

--alternatively, i would take an answer that could change my query perfomance from 2 minutes to 10 seconds.  :)

--btw, another thing that is slowing down this query is that the functions are querying a linked server...

```
create PROC [dbo].[mySP]
        @FromDate DateTime,
        @ToDate DateTime = NULL,
        @Style NVARCHAR(max),
        @ItemType  NVARCHAR(300),
        @ItemCode NVARCHAR(150)= null,
        @ItemsNotSold INT,
        @MultiplyUsage DECIMAL(18,4),
        @SParts BIT, 
        @vendorId nvarchar(50),
        @currentPage int, 
        @largeOrderSoNumbers nvarchar(300) = null,
        @excludeprojTag BIT,
        @hasOrderQty BIT = null,
        @createPO BIT = null,
        @excludeTestOrders BIT = null,
        @refresh BIT = null,
        @userid int = null,
        @positiveOverUse BIT = null
AS


SELECT @FROMDATE = @FROMDATE
,@ToDate=@ToDate
,@Style=@Style
,@ItemType=@ItemType
,@ItemCode=@ItemCode
,@ItemsNotSold=@ItemsNotSold
,@MultiplyUsage=@MultiplyUsage
,@SParts=@SParts
,@vendorId=@vendorId
,@currentPage=@currentPage
,@largeOrderSoNumbers=@largeOrderSoNumbers
,@excludeprojTag=@excludeprojTag
,@hasOrderQty =@hasOrderQty
,@createPO =@createPO
,@excludeTestOrders =@excludeTestOrders
,@refresh =@refresh
,@userid =@userid
,@positiveOverUse=@positiveOverUse

DECLARE @amountPerPage int = 400;
DECLARE @startingPoint int = (@currentpage - 1) * @amountPerPage 

SET @TODATE = NULLIF(@TODATE,'1/1/4000');
SET @ITEMCODE = NULLIF(@ITEMCODE,'');
SET @largeOrderSoNumbers = NULLIF(@LARGEORDERSONUMBERS,'');


BEGIN
    IF @Style = '-1'
        SET @Style = NULL
    IF @ItemType = '-1'
        SET @ItemType = NULL
END




SELECT
    ISNULL(c.NewQB_ListID,iit.ListID) ListID,   
    (select salesdesc from iteminventory i where i.listid = ISNULL(c.NewQB_ListID,iit.ListID)) as SalesDesc,
    isnull(inl.linename,'') + isnull(c.NewName,Name)    as ItemCode ,
    max(il.CubicMeterKD) as CubicMeterKD,

    sum(CONVERT(decimal(18,4),inl.Quantity) )
    - sum(CONVERT(decimal(18,4),inl.qtyRuleTag))
+ CONVERT(decimal(18,4),isnull(ai.qty,0))
 -CONVERT(decimal(18,4),isnull(ai.QtyRuleTag,0))   
  AS TotalQtyUesd,  
    sum(convert(decimal(18,4),isnull(inl.QtyRuleTag,0))) 
     as QtyUsedWithProjectTag,
    Convert(decimal(18,4),QuantityOnHand) as OnHand,
    CONVERT(int,ISNULL(EzQtyOnSO.Qty,0)) as OnSalesOrder,
    CONVERT(int,ISNULL(EzQtyAnyStatus.QtyLgO,0))as OnLgOrder,
    Convert(decimal(18,4),QuantityOnOrder) as OnPO,
    Convert(decimal(18,4),isnull(LargePO.lgOrderQtyOnPO,0)) as lgOrderQtyOnPO ,
    fl.LineName
    INTO #Q
FROM 
    iteminventory iit 

LEFT JOIN Lines fl
        ON iit.ParentRef_ListID = QB_LisiID 

LEFT JOIN tb_ItemList il
        ON iit.ListID = il.QBListID 


LEFT JOIN InlSales(@FromDate,@ToDate, @excludeprojtag, @excludeTestOrders) INL 
        ON IIT.LISTID = INL.ITEMREF_LISTID  


LEFT JOIN tb_CombinedItems c
        ON iit.ListID = c.ListID 

LEFT JOIN [QuantityInvoice](@FromDate, @ToDate,@excludeprojTag,@excludeTestOrders) as ai 
        ON ai.QBID = iit.ListID 

LEFT JOIN   fn_QuantityOnSalesOrder(@excludeTestOrders) AS EzQtyOnSO 
        ON iit.ListID = EzQtyOnSO.QBID

LEFT JOIN QuantityAnyStatus(@largeOrderSoNumbers, @excludeprojTag) AS EzQtyAnyStatus 
        ON iit.ListID = EzQtyAnyStatus.QBID

LEFT JOIN dbo.[FN_LargePO](@excludeTestOrders) LargePO --WITH (nolock) 
        ON LargePO.QBID = iit.ListID

WHERE 
    (@Style is null or ISNULL(c.ParentListID,ParentRef_ListID) in (SELECT Value From fn_MultiValueParameter(@Style))) AND
    (@ItemType is null or ItemTypeCode in (SELECT Value From fn_MultiValueParameter(@ItemType))) AND
    (@ItemCode is null or il.ItemCode like '%' + @ItemCode + '%') AND
    (IsActive = 1 OR c.ListID IS NOT NULL)

GROUP BY 
    ISNULL(c.NewQB_ListID,iit.ListID),
    ISNULL(c.NewName,Name),
    inl.LineName,
    QuantityOnHand,
    iit.QuantityOnOrder,
    CONVERT(int,ISNULL(EzQtyOnSO.Qty,0)),
    fl.LineName,
    CONVERT(decimal(18,4),isnull(ai.qty,0)),
    Convert(decimal(18,4),isnull(LargePO.lgOrderQtyOnPO,0)),
    CONVERT(int,ISNULL(EzQtyAnyStatus.QtyLgO,0)),
CONVERT(decimal(18,4),isnull(ai.QtyRuleTag,0))



IF @ItemsNotSold = 1
    BEGIN 
        DELETE FROM #Q
        WHERE isnull(TotalQtyUesd,0) <> 0 
    END
IF @ItemsNotSold = 2
    BEGIN 
        DELETE FROM #Q
        WHERE isnull(TotalQtyUesd,0) = 0
    END 



    SELECT 
        q.ListID,
        q.SalesDesc,
        q.ItemCode,
        MAX(isnull(q.CubicMeterKD,0)) as CubicMeterKD,
        SUM(q.TotalQtyUesd)
         TotalQtyUesd,
        SUM(q.QtyUsedWithProjectTag) as QtyUsedWithProjectTag,
        SUM(q.OnHand)  OnHand,
        SUM(q.OnSalesOrder) OnSalesOrder,
        SUM(q.OnLgOrder) OnLgOrder,
        SUM(q.OnPO) 
        - isnull(SUM(q.lgOrderQtyOnPO),0)  
        OnPO,
        SUM(q.lgOrderQtyOnPO) as lgOrderQtyOnPO,
        LineName
        INTO #QTY  
    FROM 
        #Q q 

    GROUP BY 
        q.ListID,
        q.salesdesc,
        q.ItemCode,
        q.LineName

        ;WITH Results AS
(
        SELECT 
            isnull(P.listid,'') as ListID,
            isnull(P.SalesDesc,'') as SalesDesc,
            isnull(P.itemcode,'')  as ItemCode,
            ISNULL(CubicMeterKD,0) AS CubicMeterKD,
            isnull(TotalQtyUesd,0)  as TotalQtyUsed,
            isnull(QtyUsedWithProjectTag,0) as QtyUsedWithProjectTag,
            isnull(onhand,0) as OnHand,
            isnull((OnHand - OnSalesOrder - OnLgOrder),0) as available, 
            isnull(OnLgOrder,0) as OnLgOrder,       
            isnull(OnPO,0) as OnPo,
            isnull(lgOrderQtyOnPO,0) as lgOrderQtyOnPO, 
            isnull(((OnHand - OnSalesOrder) + OnPO) ,0) AS [AvailableAndOnPo],
            isnull((TotalQtyUesd  * @MultiplyUsage) - ((OnHand - OnSalesOrder) + OnPO),0) AS [AvlOnPOminusUsed],
            isnull((((TotalQtyUesd * @MultiplyUsage) - ((OnHand - OnSalesOrder) + OnPO)) / CASE WHEN TotalQtyUesd > 0 THEN TotalQtyUesd END)*100,0) AS PctOver
            ,isnull(linename,0) as LineName,
            isnull((select price from qbdb.dbo.tb_iteminfodetail where vendorlistid = @vendorid and itemcode =isnull(P.itemcode,'')),0.0) as price
            ,isnull(pod.qtytoReOrder,0) as qtyToReOrder
            ,isnull(pod.qtytoOrder,0) as qtyToOrder
            ,isnull(pod.includePO,0) as includePO
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ITEMCODE) AS RowNum

        FROM  #qty AS p
        left join dbo.purchaseorderpreliminarydetails pod on pod.listid = P.listid and pod.deleteFlag = 0
        and headerid = (select top 1 headerid from purchaseorderpreliminary where deleteFlag = 0)
        WHERE 

        CASE WHEN @positiveOverUse = 1 THEN 
        isnull((((TotalQtyUesd * @MultiplyUsage) - ((OnHand - OnSalesOrder) + OnPO)) / CASE WHEN TotalQtyUesd > 0 THEN TotalQtyUesd END)*100,0) 
        ELSE 1 END >0

        AND
        case when  @hasOrderQty = 1 then isnull(pod.QtyToReOrder,0) else 1 end > 0 
        and 

        CASE WHEN @SPARTS = 1 THEN CASE WHEN 
        ItemCode IN (
                        'APP',
                        'CD',
                        '-S',
                        'L0',
                        'L/42',
                        'L01',
                        'Lfrgs2',
                        'Lfad2',
                        'Sfasdf9',
                        'SdafdsA',
                        'Sfasdf3',
                        'Sasdf6',
                        'asdf0',
                        'Sf6',
                        'fasdfadf2',
                        'fasdfasdf',
                        'S2236',
                        'S12342',
                        'Sdf 30',
                        'SdfE 36',
                        'fgsfgs',
                        'fasdf-fdasf',
                        'fadf',
                        'fasdf-fasdf',
                        'sdaf',
                        'adf 11"',
                        'fda 14"',
                        'fdas 24"') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 1 END = 1
    )
    SELECT (select count(rownum) from results) as totalItems,* FROM Results WHERE 
    rownum between @startingPoint + 1 and @startingPoint + @amountPerPage
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code is far from ANSI SQL.)

Comment: I don't understand, can you not just call the stored procedure from a job so that it is scheduled?

Comment: No, it has parameters that are dependent on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Have a form the users can put their parameters into before they go home, and save them into a new table in the database. Change the stored procedure to either get the parameters from this new table or to use the new table in the joins &c. The SP now doesn't need the parameters to sent to it. Finally call the SP via a Job.

Comment: no, that won't work.  they could change parameters several times a day.

Comment: And what happens when they do? If there are several sets of parameters did you plan to call the job several times in the same day? Or several times overnight? Or create a new job for each set of parameters? You must have had some plan when you asked the question...

Comment: no, my only plan was to gather ALL of the data into a single table without joins and calculations and then allow the user to put parameters into that.

Comment: What is this SP doing? Does it return data, or update/insert/delete or both?

Comment: Have you tried running the query (with representative values replacing the params) in SSMS and looked at the query plan?